# What determines the order of "featured" questions?

Tags: support, questions, bounty

What determines the order on which questions in the "featured" (questions with bounties) tab (questions with bounties) appears? When I look at it, it doesn't *appear* to be any of the following:

- Date asked
- Votes
- Bounty size
- Reputation of the original poster

Is it just a random order, or is something else going on?

Comment: It's quite ridiculous that, it is not ordered with largest bounty on the top.  There's absolutely no reason to "pay" more than the smallest bounty.  And lately http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312803/is-400-featured-questions-too-much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're ordered by time to bounty expiring (ascending).

Comment: Silly me, I didn't realize that. I was only paying attention to the information I could see in the 'featured' tab without looking closely enough at the individual question (the questions list view doesn't seem show when the bounty expires)