# Display bounty expiration time in "featured" question list

Tags: feature-request, bounty, design

Right now, when viewing the "featured" question tab, I cannot see when a bounty will expire, without viewing the question.

I'm suggesting displaying the time to bounty expiration in the question list, and not just in the question itself.

Comment: Why is the behavior Servy mentioned in your other question not good enough? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271563/what-determines-the-order-of-featured-questions

Comment: @Deduplicator The behavior Servy describes in his answer only lets me know the order in which bounties will expire, but not the actual time in which it will happen. It is somewhat of an annoyance to have to open a whole new tab, just to see this minor piece of information.